# App in Android Studio Emulator doesn't work as good as on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

when my mobile app started growing and became more complex, Android Studio Emulator started to struggle with displaying some things as expected. Sometimes its not displaying some view, or doesn't show functionality as expected. Same app installed on phone works properly and doesnt have and bugs. Im wondering if its known for AS Emulator to bug with bigger apps or i might've done something wrong with it. Im asking becouse i didnt find any related topics which got me suprised. Can you share your experience with any similar situation?

Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1):

I can tell that this is related to your pc specifications.
for example: when I ran an app on the emulator and I am running Google Chrome, the emulator shows that system has stopped.
Use [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) to ensure that your app is bugs free.

Comment: The thing is same issues occur on multiple devices with different systems/setups. However thanks for the link i ll check it out :)